# Text files on linux have "<97>" characters

Tags: linux, vim, text-editing, special-characters

When viewing a particular text file in vim or less on Linux or OS X, all the en dashes show up as highlighted "<97>" characters.

What control-sequence do I need to type in order to substitute the hyphens back? For example, the following doesn't work in vim:

```
% s/<97>/--/g
```

Typing bracket nine seven bracket is not the same as typing the actual special character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct fix is to take your file and run it through [`iconv`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) to convert from CP1252 to UTF-8.

Answer (score 6):

After some troubleshooting I seem to have figured it out. The control sequence is

```
ctrl-V X 9 7
```

Substituting that for the <97> in the vim code above works.

Comment: @marcusw: A question must be at least two days old before the OP can accept their own answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-2-days-before-accepting-my-own-answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also tell vim to re-interpret the text file using a different codepage. In command mode, enter

```
:e ++enc=cp1252
```

That should fix your em-dashes and any other unusual characters in your source text.